# Geting radiobutton value from popup window to textview

Tags: java, android, jquery

I'm kinda new to android studio, so pardon me if my question already been asked. I've tried many ways to call the value from the Radio Group I created on a popup window, but it just doesn't work. All I want is just when I click the Radio Button, the text will replace the TextView I've created on another activity.

Here is my for the popup window code:
Group.java

```
RadioGroup radiog1;
RadioButton radio;
ImageButton okbtn1;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_group);

    DisplayMetrics dm = new DisplayMetrics();

    getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(dm);

    int width = dm.widthPixels;
    int height = dm.heightPixels;

    getWindow().setLayout((int) (width * .8), (int) (height * .6));

    addListenerOnButton();
}

public void addListenerOnButton(){
    radiog1 = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.radiog1);
    okbtn1 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.okbtn1);

    okbtn1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            switch (v.getId()){
            case (R.id.okbtn1):
            int selectedId = radiog1.getCheckedRadioButtonId();
            radio = (RadioButton) findViewById(selectedId);
            radio.getText();
            finish();
            startActivity(new Intent(Group.this,Add.class));
                break;
        }
    }});
}}
```

Group.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" tools:context="badboy.todolist.Group">


<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center">

    <RadioGroup
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:baselineAligned="false"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:id="@+id/radiog1">

        <RadioButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/radio1"
            android:text="NONE"
            android:checked="true"
            android:onClick="onClick"
            />

        <RadioButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/radio2"
            android:text="NETWORK"
            android:onClick="onClick"
            />

        <RadioButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/radio3"
            android:text="MARKETING"
            android:onClick="onClick"
            />

        <RadioButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/radio4"
            android:text="GRAPHIC"
            android:onClick="onClick"
            />

        <RadioButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/radio5"
            android:text="PSDA"
            android:onClick="onClick"
            />

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_below="@+id/linearLayout10"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:gravity="center">

            <ImageButton
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/okbtn1"
                android:src="@drawable/okbtn"
                android:background="#00000000"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />
        </RelativeLayout>


    </RadioGroup>
</LinearLayout>
```

Here is the code where it should call the Radio Button value: Add.java

```
ImageButton ibtn, ibtn2, ibtn3, ibtn4,ibtn5;
TextView tvgroup;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_add);

    ibtn = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.ibtn);
    ibtn2 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.ibtn2);
    ibtn3 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.ibtn3);
    ibtn4 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.ibtn4);
    ibtn5 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.ibtn5);

    ibtn.setOnClickListener(this);
    ibtn2.setOnClickListener(this);
    ibtn3.setOnClickListener(this);
    ibtn4.setOnClickListener(this);
    ibtn5.setOnClickListener(this);
    Group group = new Group();
    tvgroup = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvgroup);
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch (v.getId()) {
        case (R.id.ibtn):
            startActivity(new Intent(this,Group.class));
            break;
        case (R.id.ibtn2):
            startActivity(new Intent(this,Due_Date.class));
            break;
        case (R.id.ibtn3):
            startActivity(new Intent(this,DueTime.class));
            break;
        case (R.id.ibtn4):
            startActivity(new Intent(this,Status.class));
            break;
        case (R.id.ibtn5):
            startActivity(new Intent(this,Assignees.class));
            break;
    }
}}
```

Add.xml

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:background="#ffa40426"
    android:id="@+id/top_bar">

    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/savebtn"
        android:nestedScrollingEnabled="false"
        android:background="#00000000"
        android:paddingTop="5dp"
        android:src="@drawable/savebtn"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/trashbtn" />

    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/trashbtn"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:src="@drawable/trash"
        android:background="#00000000"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="New Task"
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:textColor="#ffffffff"
        android:textSize="20dp" />
</RelativeLayout>

<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/top_bar"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"

    android:id="@+id/frameLayout"
    android:paddingLeft="10dp"
    android:paddingRight="10dp">


    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="GROUP"
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_gravity="left|center_vertical"
        android:textSize="20dp" />

    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/ibtn"
        android:layout_gravity="right|center_vertical"
        android:src="@drawable/arw_blk"
        android:background="#00000000" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="NONE"
        android:id="@+id/tvgroup"
        android:layout_gravity="right|center_vertical"
        android:textSize="20dp"
        android:paddingRight="30dp" />
</FrameLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="1dp"
    android:background="#ff010101"
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
    android:layout_below="@+id/frameLayout"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"></LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="80dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/linearLayout"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout2"
    android:paddingLeft="10dp"
    android:paddingRight="10dp">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="TASK NAME :"
        android:id="@+id/textView4"
        android:textSize="20dp" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/editText" />
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="1dp"
    android:background="#ff010101"
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout3"
    android:layout_below="@+id/linearLayout2"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />

<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:id="@+id/frameLayout2"
    android:layout_below="@+id/linearLayout3"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:paddingLeft="10dp"
    android:paddingRight="10dp">

    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/ibtn2"
        android:layout_gravity="right|center_vertical"
        android:src="@drawable/arw_blk"
        android:background="#00000000" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="DUE DATE"
        android:id="@+id/textView5"
        android:layout_gravity="left|center_vertical"
        android:textSize="20dp" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="NONE"
        android:id="@+id/textView6"
        android:layout_gravity="right|center_vertical"
        android:textSize="20dp"
        android:paddingRight="30dp" />

</FrameLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="1dp"
    android:background="#ff010101"
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout4"
    android:layout_below="@+id/frameLayout2"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="1dp" />

<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:id="@+id/frameLayout3"
    android:layout_below="@+id/linearLayout4"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:paddingLeft="10dp"
    android:paddingRight="10dp">

    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/ibtn3"
        android:layout_gravity="right|center_vertical"
        android:src="@drawable/arw_blk"
        android:background="#00000000" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="DUE TIME"
        android:id="@+id/textView7"
        android:layout_gravity="left|center_vertical"
        android:textSize="20dp" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="NONE"
        android:id="@+id/textView8"
        android:layout_gravity="right|center_vertical"
        android:textSize="20dp"
        android:paddingRight="30dp" />
</FrameLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="1dp"
    android:background="#ff010101"
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout5"
    android:layout_below="@+id/frameLayout3"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:id="@+id/frameLayout4"
    android:layout_below="@+id/linearLayout5"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:paddingLeft="10dp"
    android:paddingRight="10dp">

    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/ibtn4"
        android:layout_gravity="right|center_vertical"
        android:src="@drawable/arw_blk"
        android:background="#00000000" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="STATUS"
        android:id="@+id/textView9"
        android:layout_gravity="left|center_vertical"
        android:textSize="20dp" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="NONE"
        android:id="@+id/textView10"
        android:layout_gravity="right|center_vertical"
        android:textSize="20dp"
        android:paddingRight="30dp" />
</FrameLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="1dp"
    android:background="#ff010101"
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout6"
    android:layout_below="@+id/frameLayout4"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:id="@+id/frameLayout5"
    android:layout_below="@+id/linearLayout6"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:paddingLeft="10dp"
    android:paddingRight="10dp">

    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/ibtn5"
        android:layout_gravity="right|center_vertical"
        android:src="@drawable/arw_blk"
        android:background="#00000000" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="ASSIGNEES"
        android:id="@+id/textView11"
        android:layout_gravity="left|center_vertical"
        android:textSize="20dp" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="NONE"
        android:id="@+id/textView12"
        android:layout_gravity="right|center_vertical"
        android:textSize="20dp"
        android:paddingRight="30dp" />
</FrameLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="1dp"
    android:background="#ff010101"
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout7"
    android:layout_below="@+id/frameLayout5"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it is easy just put the string data in the intent and receive it from the second activity like this :

Group.java :

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Group.this,Add.class);
intent.putExtra("SomeTag",""+radio.getText());
startActivity(intent);
```

Add.java :

```
 public void onCreate(Bundle b){

 Bundle extra = getIntent().getExtras();
    if (extra != null) {
        String textViewName = extra.getString("SomeTag");
        textView.setText(textViewName);
 }
```

Comment: I tried your code, but it seems like the apps crash as I click the submit button on my Group.java

Comment: OK, I tried again after several hours of trying, and it's functioning properly, thanks mate.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following website:

[Radio Buttons|Android Developers](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/radiobutton.html)

It is a full tutorial from Android itself.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use both setOnCheckedChangeListener and onCheckedChanged.

```
t=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.textview1);
 rg=(RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.RadioGroupID);
        rbFirst=(RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.radioFirst);
        rbSecond=(RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.radioSecond);

        rg.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {

                if(checkedId==R.id.rbFirst) {
                    t.setText("Do somthing....");
                }
                else if(checkedId==R.id.rbSecond)
                {
                    t.setText("Do somthing else...");
                }
            }
        });
```

Comment: it crashes as soon as I click the radio button. I'll try a bit harder using the code you gave me.